# How to get a POST request, and broadcast same POST request to a predefined list of urls in python

Tags: python, http

This was a task asked for me in an interview but I didn't really understand it and so wasn't able to solve it
I Know how to perform a POST request using the requests library, and I can perform a POST request to a set of urls like this

```
import requests
URLS = ['www.url1.com', 'www.url2.com'] 
data = {'param1':value}
for url in URLS:
    r = requests.post(url, data)
```

but what does it mean to get the POST request??

Comment: It means you should provide web-service which would accept POST-requests, and place your broadcasting code inside request-handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a server to receive POST request, which we call it Restful request.

Flask is one of tools to build your python server up quickly.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, request

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 9000
URLS = ['www.url1.com', 'www.url2.com']

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def receive_data():
    value = request.json
    data = {'param1': value}
    for url in URLS:
        r = requests.post(url, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, threaded=True)  # make your server receive the request in multiply threads
```

Just run it and try sending something to your server by postman or others.